# "Left join" 0 - 100 percentiles onto stat values in javascript

Tags: javascript, left-join, data-manipulation

We have what seems like a challenging data manipulation issue involving two javascript array's of objects. The first array `stats` stores basketball statistics, and the second array `pctiles` store percentiles for the stats that are associated with the statistics. See below for a small example of our `stats` and `pctiles`:

```js
let stats = [
  { group: 'a', fgPct: 0.44, fg2Pct: 0.48 },
  { group: 'a', fgPct: 0.41, fg2Pct: 0.46 },
  { group: 'b', fgPct: 0.40, fg2Pct: 0.34 },
  { group: 'b', fgPct: 0.38, fg2Pct: 0.31 }
]

let pctiles = [
  { group: 'a', pctile: 0, fgPct: 0.385, fg2Pct: 0.425 },
  { group: 'a', pctile: 1, fgPct: 0.398, fg2Pct: 0.436 },
  { group: 'a', pctile: 2, fgPct: 0.412, fg2Pct: 0.458 },
  { group: 'a', pctile: 3, fgPct: 0.431, fg2Pct: 0.465 },
  { group: 'a', pctile: 4, fgPct: 0.452, fg2Pct: 0.475 },
  { group: 'a', pctile: 5, fgPct: 0.468, fg2Pct: 0.491 },
  { group: 'b', pctile: 0, fgPct: 0.371, fg2Pct: 0.291 },
  { group: 'b', pctile: 1, fgPct: 0.382, fg2Pct: 0.301 },
  { group: 'b', pctile: 2, fgPct: 0.392, fg2Pct: 0.306 },
  { group: 'b', pctile: 3, fgPct: 0.412, fg2Pct: 0.323 },
  { group: 'b', pctile: 4, fgPct: 0.425, fg2Pct: 0.342 },
  { group: 'b', pctile: 5, fgPct: 0.434, fg2Pct: 0.346 }
]
```

The full version of `pctiles` goes from 0 - 100 for each group `a` and `b`, and the values for `fgPct` and `fg2Pct` correspond to the 0th, 1st, 2nd, etc. percentiles for these metrics from our much larger `stats` array.

We need to *"left join"* the `pctiles` onto the `stats`, and I use quotes for *left join* because it is not technically a left join. See below for necessary output:

```
let statsWithPctiles = [
  { group: 'a', fgPct: 0.44, fg2Pct: 0.48, fgPctPctile: 4, fg2PctPctile: 5 },
  { group: 'a', fgPct: 0.41, fg2Pct: 0.46, fgPctPctile: 2, fg2PctPctile: 3 },
  { group: 'b', fgPct: 0.40, fg2Pct: 0.34, fgPctPctile: 3, fg2PctPctile: 4 },
  { group: 'b', fgPct: 0.38, fg2Pct: 0.31, fgPctPctile: 1, fg2PctPctile: 3 }
]
```

To clarify on this output for the first object:

- `fgPct` of 0.44, for group `a`, is between the 3rd %ile (.431) and the 4th %ile (.452). Always set `fgPctPctile` to the upper %ile (4)
- `fg2Pct` of 0.48, for group `a`, is between the 4th %ile (.475) and the 5th %ile (.491). Always set `fg2PctPctile` to the upper %ile (5)

We need to do this for every metric in every object in `stats`, seeing which 2 percentiles the `stats` value falls between, and setting the metricPctile value based on the upper percentile, and it needs to be done somewhat efficiently as our actual `stats` array of objects can have a few hundred objects, each with 50 or more metrics.

**Edit:** I am working on a solution to this and will post it soon, although I am concerned that it is not very performant.

**Edit2:** Update on our current, slow approach:

```
// for this example, we can ignore the toObject(), however I need these for some reason to get to the object in our fetched results...

// map over the "stats" array
let statsWithPctiles = stats.map((rowA, idxA) => {
    // first filter for group 'a' or 'b' (filter to match stats object)
    let thesePctiles = pctiles.filter((rowB, idxB) => {
        return (rowB.toObject().group === rowA._id.group);
    });

    // second, for loop over the keys
    Object.keys(rowA).forEach((metric, idxC) => {

        if (metric !== '_id' && metric !== 'group') {
            let filteredPctiles = thesePctiles.filter((rowC, idxD) => {
                return (rowC.toObject()[metric] > rowA[metric]);
            });

            let mappedValues = filteredPctiles.map(rowD => rowD.toObject()[metric]);
            let maxPctile = Math.max(...mappedValues);
            rowA[`${metric}Pctile`] = maxPctile
        }
    });
});
```

...which isn't working yet, as I haven't gotten the code in the inner `forEach()` right yet.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Your `pctiles` array seems to be sorted so binary search may be a good approach here.

Comment: I'm going to update the post soon - I have a double nested loop that (a) loops over each object in `stats`, then (b) loops over each key in the corresponding object, (c) filters the `pctiles` based on the key value in the nested loop, and (d) sets the pctile.

Percentiles are sorted yes, as the 2nd `pctile` value for a stat is higher than the 1st `pctile` value. There are a few metrics that are sorted in reverse order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```js
let stats = [
  { group: 'a', fgPct: 0.44, fg2Pct: 0.48 },
  { group: 'a', fgPct: 0.41, fg2Pct: 0.46 },
  { group: 'b', fgPct: 0.40, fg2Pct: 0.34 },
  { group: 'b', fgPct: 0.38, fg2Pct: 0.31 }
]

let pctiles = [
  { group: 'a', pctile: 0, fgPct: 0.385, fg2Pct: 0.425 },
  { group: 'a', pctile: 1, fgPct: 0.398, fg2Pct: 0.436 },
  { group: 'a', pctile: 2, fgPct: 0.412, fg2Pct: 0.458 },
  { group: 'a', pctile: 3, fgPct: 0.431, fg2Pct: 0.465 },
  { group: 'a', pctile: 4, fgPct: 0.452, fg2Pct: 0.475 },
  { group: 'a', pctile: 5, fgPct: 0.468, fg2Pct: 0.491 },
  { group: 'b', pctile: 0, fgPct: 0.371, fg2Pct: 0.291 },
  { group: 'b', pctile: 1, fgPct: 0.382, fg2Pct: 0.301 },
  { group: 'b', pctile: 2, fgPct: 0.392, fg2Pct: 0.306 },
  { group: 'b', pctile: 3, fgPct: 0.412, fg2Pct: 0.323 },
  { group: 'b', pctile: 4, fgPct: 0.425, fg2Pct: 0.342 },
  { group: 'b', pctile: 5, fgPct: 0.434, fg2Pct: 0.346 }
]

let statsWithPctiles = stats;

stats.forEach(function(stat,stat_index){
  let fgPCT = false;
  let fg2PCT = false;
  let group_pctiles = pctiles.filter(pctiless => pctiless.group == stat["group"]).sort((a, b)=> a.pctile - b.pctile).forEach(function(pctile){
      if(stat["fgPct"] <= pctile["fgPct"] && fgPCT == false)
      {
        statsWithPctiles[stat_index]["fgPctPctile"] = pctile["pctile"];
        fgPCT = true;
      }
      if(stat["fg2Pct"] <= pctile["fg2Pct"] && fg2PCT == false)
      {
        statsWithPctiles[stat_index]["fg2PctPctile"] = pctile["pctile"];
        fg2PCT = true;
      }
  });
  
});

console.log(statsWithPctiles);
```

Comment: you created a new stackoverflow account just to help w/ my question - thank you so much

Comment: Yeah, Thank you. It's my pleasure to help others


you can customize the code if you want.